# How to update a property in Argo cron?

Tags: devops, argo

I can get the details of my argo crontabs with a command like the following:

```
argo cron get my-cron-id -o json
```

Now, I need to update the following property for all my crons:

```
spec.workflowSpec.templates[0].container.image
```

as that container image has a bug and I released a new version of it.

Is it possible to update that property for all my crons? (I know I can delete an create a new one, but I would like to update it to maintain the cron id, as I have a reference to it in my database)